# Flutter - Nested OnTap doesn't work on ListTile

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

[1. When I open Dialog, click item3 in ListView.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj6WL.png)

[2. But, Item3 background color doesn't changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOcFR.png)

[3. When I open Dialog again, item3's background color in ListView changed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryqtD.png)

```
child: TextField(
            readOnly: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              // var dialog = AlertDialog(
              Get.defaultDialog(
                title: '',
                // shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),

                content: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                    child: Scrollbar(
                      isAlwaysShown: true,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: _list.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return new Container(
                                color: this.tappedIndex == index ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(_list[index]),
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      this.tappedIndex = index;
                                      // dropdownValue = _list[index];
                                    });
                                  },
                                )
                            );
                          })
                    ),
                  ),
)
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a different `StatefulWidget` for the `ListView`? So that when `setState(...)` is called, it will focus rebuilding the `ListView` only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how getx handles the dialogs (that is, how `Get.defaultDialog` works) but assuming it's simillar to `showDialog`, then you can't refresh a widget inside of a dialog without using an independent state management inside of a dialog or a `StreamBuilder`

Basically you have to

- transform `tappedIndex` into a `StreamController`, e.g. `BehaviorSubject` from `rxdart`
- wrap `Get.defaultDialog`'s `content` parameter with a `StreamBuilder` (or one of the children that depends should be rebuilt upon value change, `ListView` in your case)
- subscribe to `tappedIndex` inside the newly created `StreamBuilder`

Or alternatively create a `StatefulWidget` that would be placed inside of your dialog, that upon state change would also update the `index` value of a `StatefulWidget` outside the dialog.

Personally, I think the solution with `Stream`s is the way to go.